# "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_PACKER_CONFIG" code when instantiating ably-java

Tags: java, real-time, ably-realtime

I'm trying to use Ably's java SDK but when I'm trying to instantiate the library, I get the error above. Any idea why?

*(disclaimer: I am a developer advocate for Ably, and posting and self-answering a [commonly asked support question](https://support.ably.io/support/solutions/articles/3000073569--java-lang-nosuchfielderror-default-packer-config-code-when-instantiating-ably-java) here on Stack Overflow so our users can find this more easily)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that this error is an indication that I'm using a 'thin jar' (a jar file containing just ably-java) without installing its dependencies. This won't work; instead, one should follow the installation instructions at https://github.com/ably/ably-java#installation